# What is the simpliest way to send myself email from a server?

Tags: email, ubuntu

I'm looking for the simpliest way to be able to send admin emails (backups, notifications) from an ubuntu server to my gmail address.

What is the best way to do that ? Should I just create a gmail account and use imap ? Or should I install postfix or something similar ? (I'm concerned about keeping it lightweight and avoid the need for too much configuration/security tweaks).

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setup ubuntu server to send mail()](http://serverfault.com/questions/119105/setup-ubuntu-server-to-send-mail)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple Mail System for Ubuntu?](http://serverfault.com/questions/73769/simple-mail-system-for-ubuntu) and [Receive email alerts from Linux file server](http://serverfault.com/questions/79899/receive-email-alerts-from-linux-file-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just install Postfix. Default installation (internet site) will do.

In `/etc/aliases` add yourself as the alias to root

```
root: youraddresshere@gmail.com
```

You have to also run `newaliases` to update the indexed db file.

Comment: As long as there is no firewall blocking outgoing SMTP this will work just fine. Otherwise you might have to configure postfix to use a smarthost. +1

Comment: @pehrs: yeah that is true. +1

Comment: Postfix is usually overkill IMO, I use nullmailer to keep a minimal footprint.

Comment: I wasn't aware of nullmailer and looked at it - apparently it works by connecting itself to remote smtp, right ?

Comment: We used to use nullmailer. But I replaced it with Postfix. It is much more easier. nullmailer queue management is just seems wrong. (It seems to me that if you reject a mail upstream it will stay in the queue forever, because nullmailer never discards a message.)

Answer (score 1):

If any of your servers are hosted a well known source for spam - which now include many cloud providers and hosters, any alias forwarding to gmail (or any such webmail provider) is likely to fail due to RBL policy.

What i usually do is setup a "google app for your domain" account, and add the necessary SPF record to the DNS zone so that google MXs will accept mail relayed through my hosts.

Comment: Well thank you - I just figured this out during my tests (my emails gradually went to spam then ended being delivered!). I believe I'll use SendGrid or Google Apps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have mail setup, you use mailx to send out email from a script...

my-backup-script.sh | mailx -s "results from backups" myemail@myhost.com

echo "just a test" | mailx -s "please ignore this" myemail@myhost.com

cat << EOF | mailx -s "more tests" myemail@myhost.com

this is a long

test of email in a

shell script

EOF

Answer (score -1):

It seems that [configure sendmail to send through Gmail SMTP](http://www.phinesolutions.com/sendmail-gmail-smtp-relay-howto.html) is easier for you.

Comment: I think this is neither easy nor necessary.